# Test for heterogeneity of data in regression

Tags: regression

I am running regression where it is suggested in the literature heterogeneity may occur. We have customers who come back more than one time (every time they come back we are rated again). I am running models where these multiple cases exist (the dependent variable will be income and separately employment the former a linear model and the latter a logistic regression). I have been looking for a test of heterogeneity, but other than meta-analysis (which I am not doing) I have not found one.

Note that I don't care about the standard errors being influenced by the heterogeneity if that matters. I have the entire population. But in this case it has been suggested that the heterogeneity might bias the calculated effect size (the slopes).

Comment: Something is amiss. If you have the whole population, then there is no inference going on. You’re not estimating the population parameter. You’re calculating it. There isn’t bias any more than there is bias when you calculate the mean through the $\mathbb{E}[X]$ integral. That’s the value, and you know that with certainty.

Comment: I do have the whole population. I thought having multiple cases would bias the calculated results because it was possible that different cases would have different slopes on the DV (it has been argued that the first case when someone closes would have a different relationship with the DV than later cases for the same person would). That is the slope is for all cases and when a customer closes and comes back a second time the first case would relate differently to the DV than the second one (heterogeneity of effect).

Comment: I guess what I am really asking is can a slope every be biased when you have the whole population. In this case you have heterogeneity in other cases you might have and excluded variable.

Comment: Bias is the expected difference between the population parameter and the value (statistic) used to estimate it. When the value is the parameter itself, that expectation is zero. (In fact, the difference is zero, not just the expectation.) If you do have the whole population, though, testing and other forms of inference do not make sense. The point of inference is to try to guess intelligently about an unknown population. If you have the whole population, you don’t have to guess. // I have my doubts that you really have the whole population, but perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: I am a data analyst for a state agency and we are analyzing our own members, all we care about for this analysis. It is highly unlikely that there is anyone we serve I don't have. The way you discus bias is never the way I thought of it before. For instance, if a and b drive the dependent variable, and a and b are related and you leave b out of the model than the relationship between a and the dependent variable would be wrong in your model even with the whole population. To me that is bias, but maybe not. Or if you use  a linear relationship for non-linear data.